# Laravel 5.4 route list exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing

I'm trying list all the route list using artisan command `php artisan route:list`

I'm getting following error,

```
[ErrorException]
  You must set the encryption key going forward to improve the security of this library - see this page for more info
  rmation https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/v5-security-improvements/
```

Comment: Have you generated application key correctly ?

Comment: i think your application key is not valid, run `php artisan key:generate` command to generate the new key

Comment: first i have updated composer then i ran `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: @RAUSHAN KUMAR  @Sagar Gautam  even i did `composer dump-autoload` but still i'm getting the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the latest `oauth-server 5.1.4` update, you should set an encryption key which is not implemented yet in `passport 2.x`.

An easy and fast fix to this is by using `passport 3.x` which uses `oauth-server 6.x` by updating your `composer.json` file with:

```
"laravel/passport": "^3.0"
```

Then

```
composer update
```

or, try

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data storage/oauth-*.key
sudo chmod 600 storage/oauth-*.key
```

may be it solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for your response, i'm using windows, what would be the commands

Comment: thank you that worked, but i'm getting a new error `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  syntax error, unexpected '}'` i couldn't figure out where the error is in my routes files

Comment: @MrRobot check in the routes.php, i think you added one extra closing brackets `}`

Comment: i did refactor my `routes.php` i'm getting all data and stuff. i'm getting the error only when i ran the `php artisan route:list` command

Comment: You saved my day.. !